# Spring Boot Application read csv file on docker container apache spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

When I tried to read csv files with Spring boot app on my local machine and apache/spark on docker container exception occurred.

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: file:/home/sparkdata/data.csv.
```

I connected to the spark master remotely(I am mentioning on docker) successfully. here is my java spring SparkConfig and and SparkSession code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("appName")
                .setSparkHome("home")
                .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
Dataset<Row> dataset=sparkSession
                .read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .load("/home/sparkdata/data.csv");
        dataset.printSchema();
```

and docker compose yml here which I mounted to the docker container my localstorage and some other configs:
version: '3.4'

```
`services:
  spark:
    container_name: master
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    networks:
      - spark-network
    volumes:
      - "/Users/sparkdata:/home/sparkdata:rw"

  spark-worker-1:
    container_name: worker_1
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    depends_on:
      - spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_WORKER_PORT=9091
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
      - "7001:7000"
    networks:
      - spark-network
    volumes:
      - "/Users/sparkdata:/home/sparkdata:rw"
  spark-worker-2:
    container_name: worker_2
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    depends_on:
      - spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_WORKER_PORT=9092
    ports:
      - "9092:8080"
      - "7002:7000"
    networks:
      - spark-network
    volumes:
      - "/Users/sparkdata:/home/sparkdata:rw"
networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge`
```

When I run compose file, it works fine well, I can see mounted path to docker, and file can be seen in docker spark container. How can I read file with spring boot remotely connected apache spark master on the docker container. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Overall, Is it possible to read file  which mounted path in docker from outside of the docker , from java app